# Calculate total of 2 different variables to 2 decimal places

Tags: jquery

How can I make the outcome of the following sum be to 2 decimal places?

```
114.95 + 6.95 = 121.90
```

This is what I have tried, but the outcome of this code is `114.956.95`

```
var Bezorgkosten = this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
var Subtotaal = <?= $l_TotaalPrijs ?>;
var Totaalkosten = parseFloat(Subtotaal).toFixed(2) + parseFloat(Bezorgkosten).toFixed(2);
$('.bezorgkosten').html(Bezorgkosten);
$('.totaalkosten').html(Totaalkosten);
```

I don't know why it doesn't calculate? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `toFixed()` returns a string, which means that `+` becomes a concatenation instead of an addition. You need to use `parseFloat()`, make the calculation and then use `toFixed()` before showing the values. Try this:

```
var Bezorgkosten = this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
var Subtotaal = <?= $l_TotaalPrijs ?>;
var Totaalkosten = parseFloat(Subtotaal) + parseFloat(Bezorgkosten);
$('.bezorgkosten').html(Bezorgkosten.toFixed(2));
$('.totaalkosten').html(Totaalkosten.toFixed(2));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1ntbsmv2/)

Comment: if i use with this variable
`var Bezorgkosten = 5;
var Subtotaal = 10;`
it works

if i use with this variables
`var Bezorgkosten = this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
var Subtotaal = <?= $l_TotaalPrijs ?>;`

it dont works

Comment: What are those values? Can you provide the actual output.

Comment: i got it! `<?= $l_TotaalPrijs ?>` makes it a string so need to parse it to a float too `parseFloat(<?= $l_TotaalPrijs ?>)`

Answer (score 0):

toFixed() convert your floats to strings, that's why it concatenates your values instead of making your sum, you should use it after your addition:

```
var Totaalkosten = parseFloat(Subtotaal) + parseFloat(Bezorgkosten);
Totaalkosten = Totaalkosten.toFixed(2);
```